# Why I have Unsupported platform for fsevents Error on laravel 5.5 project

Tags: laravel-5, npm-install

I try to run my old laravel 5.5  and got a lot of errors on npm install like:

```
...
npm WARN rollback Rolling back cryptiles@3.1.2 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back rc@1.2.7 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back fsevents@1.2.4 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back request@2.83.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back sass-graph@2.2.4 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/yargs'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-gyp@3.6.2 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-10-18T11_45_59_931Z-debug.log

And vwery big 2018-10-18T11_45_59_931Z-debug.log file at https://pastebin.com/UA3Zb4bH:
```

I tried to google but failed...

composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.3",
        "rcrowe/twigbridge": "^0.9.5",
        "sebastiansulinski/dotenv": "^2.0",
        "sebastiansulinski/php-backup": "^2.0",
        "spatie/dropbox-api": "^1.6",
        "spatie/flysystem-dropbox": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.1.10"
    }
}

$ npm -v
6.4.1
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp$ node -v
v10.11.0
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/csvp$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
4.15.0-36-generic
x86_64
```

I tried to run command:

```
npm cache clean && npm install node-sass
```

but I got :

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.                                       
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                               
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.                                                                                                                          

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                                                                                   
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-10-19T03_40_05_165Z-debug.log
```

Also I tried to delete node_modules and /tmp/empty-cache directories manually, but 
anyway I have error with Unsupported platform for fsevents. I tried to clear some old cache.

Why error and how to fix it ?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I still suffer this problem...
If there is a way to recollect project from the start?

Comment: looks like command
npm cache --force clean && npm install --force node-sass 
helped!

Comment: Little late comment - First of all, I'm an absolute Laravel beginner so please don't judge.

I solved it by deleting;
node_modules/@esbuild folder, then run  - npm i (This creates new @esbuild), then run - npm run build and all is good again.